# Validate access rights on method call

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a Java EE application which enables logged in users to perform actions on the system depending on their role (such as "administrator" or "guest".)

To do so, I need a simple and elegant way to check whether the currently logged in user is allowed to perform a method without having to put an if statement at the very beginning of each method to check whether the user is privileged.

My idea is to put a custom annotation before methods that should be restricted in usage and to evaluate that annotation when it's called:

```
@RestrictAccessToUserGroups("admin")
private void doSomethingAwesome() {

  // If the currently logged in user is not member 
  // of "admin" user group, this method doesn't get called
}
```

To me, this looks like a pretty flexible and elegant way.

Unfortunately I don't know how to trigger a method which gets called the same time `doSomethingAwesome()` gets called to check whether the called method has annotations and to parse them.

Any idea how to achieve that (without using a third-party library)?

Comment: Is it a Web application? If so, you can use sessions and Filters. If you want to do a separation of concerns (pattern) you should use CDI with custom annotations.

Comment: Also, java EE servers implement user management by roles. These roles are managed by the container and you can assign roles on your code.

Comment: Yes, it's a web app. Java EE's role management is not flexible enough (I didn't mention it, but I need to manage a flexible number of roles) and I would prefer a "code level access control" over an access control just based on filters (which examines the URL.)

Answer (score 1):

Well then you should look into CDI and Interceptors. Here's a tiny example:

A bean can have multiple annotated implementations that will depend on user roles. First, you define your users annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface RestrictAccessToUserGroups {
    UserGroup value();
}

public enum UserGroup {
    ADMIN,
    SECOND_LEVEL
}
```

Then you can use this annotation in different implementations of a bean:

```
@RestrictAccessToUserGroups(ADMIN)
@RequestScoped
public class AdminAwesomeBeanImpl implements AwesomeBean{

public void doSomethingAwesome() {
//some stuff
}

}
```

Then you can inject this bean implementation in a JSF page, a JAX-RS service, etc.

```
@Inject
@RestrictAccessToUserGroups(ADMIN)
private AwesomeBean awesomeBean;
```

If you want "to trigger a method which gets called the same time", then what you need are interceptors. Let's say you want to perform a user validation on method invocation (doSomethingAwesome). First you have to define your interceptor annotation binding:

```
@Inherited 
@InterceptorBinding 
@Target({TYPE,METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface RestrictAccessToUserGroupsValidator {
    UserGroup value(); 
}
```

Then you implement your interceptor which is going to validate a user on method call:

```
@RestrictAccessToUserGroups(ADMIN)
@Interceptor
public class AdminValidator {
@AroundInvoke
    public Object validate(InvocationContext ctx) throws NoSuchMethodException, Exception{
//some user validation
}
}
```

Then, you add your interceptor annotation on your business bean:

```
@RestrictAccessToUserGroupsValidator(ADMIN)
@RestrictAccessToUserGroups(ADMIN)
@RequestScoped
public class AdminAwesomeBeanImpl implements AwesomeBean{

public void doSomethingAwesome() {
//some stuff
}       
}
```

Don't forget to add your interceptor into your beans.xml file:

```
<interceptors>
        <class>the.package.AdminValidator</class>
    </interceptors>
```

I hope this gives you and idea on how would it work. :)